# how can I get a function to store a new variable, with a value assigned to it, after it has been passed

Tags: python, function, variables

I want to store a folder name as the variable x so it can be used later in a different function but when I go to use x, it tells me that it is undefined. But only once it is time for the function to execute again.

```
import os
def start():
    s = 0
    for folder in next(os.walk('E:'))[1][s]:
        x = folder #for each value of s, make x = the folder's name
        s += 1
        return x
if __name__ == '__start__':
    start()
fdrname = r'E:\\' + x
stem = fdrname[4:6]
n = stem + 'F'
def main():
    fdrname = r'E:\\' + x
    stem = fdrname[4:6]
    n = stem + 'F'
    i = 0
    for filename in os.listdir(fdrname):
        dst = x + n + str(i) + ".jpg"
        src = x + filename      
        os.rename(src, dst)
        i += 1
if __name__ == '__main__': 
    main(x)
print(fdrname)
```

when I run it, this is what is output

```
----> 21 main(x)

NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

Comment: return the folder name variable x and pass to the function where u wanna use it

Comment: How would I go about passing it

Answer (score 0):

just return x from the function and store it in main() to different variable